# Run function at a specific time of a day

Tags: wp-cron

I have tried this solution but I can't get it to work
[Run function at specific time](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126315/run-function-at-specific-time)

Here is my example:

```
//this is for testing purposes
function my_cron_schedules($schedules){
if(!isset($schedules["1min"])){
    $schedules["1min"] = array(
        'interval' => 60,
        'display' => __('Once a minute'));
}

return $schedules;
}
add_filter('cron_schedules','my_cron_schedules');

if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_scheduled_event' ) ) { wp_schedule_event( 
strtotime( '2019-01-04 19:39:00' ), '1min', 'my_scheduled_event' ); }

add_action( 'my_scheduled_event', 'update_ratings' );

function update_ratings() { 
//do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Did you initiate a request to trigger the event? WordPress cron isn't true cron- it will only run when someone loads a page on your site.

Comment: The problem was in scheduled cron jobs. While testing I had previously set cron job for the same hook. After inspecting cron jobs I managed to delete that test schedule and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in scheduled cron jobs. While testing I had previously set cron job for the same hook. After inspecting cron jobs I managed to delete that test schedule and now it is working.